# How can I delete a character in vim

Tags: vim

How can I delete single quote character `'` if it appears at the beginning or the end of a line?

something like :

```
:%s/^['] or [']$//
```

Comment: or is \|. You can always google out for question like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%s/^'\|'$//g
```

this will do the job

Note that this remove both leading and ending single quotes if they appeared. E.g.:

`'fo'o'xyz' => fo'o'xyz`

If there could be leading/trailing spaces before/after the single quotes, you could do:

```
%s/^\s*'\|'\s*$//g
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
:%s/^'// | %s/'$//
```

Comment: what if  `'` isn't the very first character but there are some whitespaces at the beginning of the line?

Comment: You can use \s*, it stands for 0 or more whitespaces, but you if want to keep the space, you have to save it: :%s/^\\(\s*\\)'/\1/ | %s/'$//

Answer (score 1):

Another method, just for fun:

```
:%s/\s*^'\(.*\)'\s*$/\1
```